# How do I get the index from the last occurence of a character in a string sql?

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, substring

I'm using the following to find a city state in my database.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(Location, PATINDEX( '%(%' , Location), LEN(Location))
   FROM myTable
```

This gets me the following type of results.

```
(San Jose, CA)
(Los Angeles, CO)
(A Place)(Miami, FL)
...
```

I'm wanting to disregard the first set of parathesis in cases like the 3rd example.

I tried using REVERSE() but no luck with it, perhaps I was using it incorrectly or maybe that isn't my solution.  Can anyone help out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can;

```
;with T(f) as (
    select '' union 
    select 'xxx' union 
    select 'xxx (yyy)' union 
    select 'xxx (yyy) (zzz)'
)
select 
    right(f, patindex('%(%', reverse(f) + '('))
from T

>>

(No column name)

xxx
(yyy)
(zzz)
```

Remove the +'(' to get blanks for no parens.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SQL Server's string manipulation functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). In particular at [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). This should be what you're looking for.

However, as a long term remedy to problems like this, schema refactoring is recommended. Storing complex data as strings and applying string manipulation later is often less efficient than storing data in the form that is easy to analyse by queries.